# USB Dongle Recognition in Android - Beaglebone

Tags: android, c, linux, beagleboard, usb-modeswitch

**Issue  :**

Some of the Huawei USB Dongles not recognized by Android JellyBean4.1.2 in Beaglebone.

**In Detail  :**

I am working with BeagleBone running on Android JellyBean4.1.2 .

`Huawei - E1731 [Locked] , Huawei - E303D [Locked]`  are ***working fine*** in this platform.

`Huawei E303F , Huawei E303F (Both Factory Unlocked)` are ***not recognized*** by the OS
(Communication files not generated)

### Work-Around done by myself

1. Change the Dongle's Mode to Modem Only Mode using AT command

[image]

2. Add the vendor ID & Product ID to init.devicename.sh (Force the kernal to recognize the USB Dongle)

[image]

3. Change the USB-Modeswitch File with VID & PID

[image]

Now the mentioned USB Dongles are working fine .

[image]

- But i want to find the **root cause** & have to fix it .
- Is there any option to fix it by building Android OS from source ? If yes , How ? Which are the files need to change ?
- Why some dongles directly recognized without the mentioned work-around ?

### UPDATE

As **skoperst** said , i have checked `option.c` in  `kernel_dir/drivers/usb/serial/option.c`

[image]

- Is there any solution **`other than hard-coding Device VID & PID`** .
- I need some more generic solution , to facilitate a **`Plug & Play`** mechanism.
- How the **`Plug & Play works in linux`** .If it is possible with **`linux kernal`** , is it also possible with Android?

*Your great suggestions appreciated . Lot of thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is with the kernel running on the device you use and not about the Android OS.

Which USB device are supported(I.E. which combination of vid/pid) depends on which sets are defined in the kernel, its hard-coded.

Specifically you need USB serial device definition(AKA ttyUSB) for you specific VID&PID and they are usually located in: **kernel_dir/drivers/usb/serial/option.c**
That's also true for any other driver you wish the device will recognize.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer.I will try it and let you know.Is there any other solution without hard-coding VID & PID ?