# How to Connect USB device with my Android device

Tags: android, android-usb

In the example [link](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/tree/master/usbSerialExamples) given in github am unable to detect my usb device using this example and moreover can anyone tell me how can I specify the device product id and vendor id to device_filter.xml. The main idea of mine to test this example is to connect a android device to a thermal printer POS using USB so first if this example detects my device I can further go ahead and use this library to have a handshake between my POS and android device.

Please help me if you have any other suggestion ideas.

Thanks

Comment: You may get some clues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27616045/usb-dongle-recognition-in-android-beaglebone

Answer (score 1):

Add your device "Vendor ID" in `adb_usb.ini` which is located in `.android/adb_usb.ini`.

P.S This doesn't guarantee you device is detected by android system